# Mongoose deleteMany with "like" operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to delete all MongodDB documents from a collection that contains a specific string in a field. (I'm using mongoose)

The SQL query would be like

```sql
DELETE FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%test%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with with [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator:

```js
collection.deleteMany({ field: { $regex: 'your_string' } });
```